xapian-full-1.2.3 not able to install succesffully
Application not starting after ubutu patch upgrade.
/home/azureuser/app2/current
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.13
acts_as_xapian: No Ruby bindings for Xapian installed
/home/azureuser/app2/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts_as_xapian-0.1.3/lib/acts_as_xapian/search.rb:8:in `<class:Search>': uninitialized constant ActsAsXapian::Search::Xapian (NameError)
        from /home/azureuser/app2/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts_as_xapian-0.1.3/lib/acts_as_xapian/search.rb:5:in `<module:ActsAsXapian>'
        from /home/azureuser/app2/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts_as_xapian-0.1.3/lib/acts_as_xapian/search.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/azureuser/app2/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts_as_xapian-0.1.3/lib/acts_as_xapian.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/azureuser/app2/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts_as_xapian-0.1.3/lib/acts_as_xapian.rb:1:in `each'
        from /home/azureuser/app2/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/acts_as_xapian-0.1.3/lib/acts_as_xapian.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from /home/azureuser/app2/releases/20240702075626/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/azureuser/app2/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
        from /home/azureuser/app2/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

gem install error
current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/xapian-full-1.2.3
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/bin/ruby -rrubygems /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR\=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/xapian-full-1.2.3 RUBYLIBDIR\=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/xapian-full-1.2.3
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Config
Did you mean?  RbConfig
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/xapian-full-1.2.3/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Ruby version
azureuser@vm-delex-web-upgrade:~/app2/current$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-linux]

That is a 14 year-old gem that does not appear to be actively supported -- probably time to replace it with another xapian implementation.

try reinstalling nokogiri
gem uninstall nokogiri
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries

if it still doesn't work make sure the dependency is installed:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxapian-dev

gem install xapian-full

